# Error initializer element is not constant

Tags: c

I am having trouble with my code, and I can not solve ....

the code snippet where the error is reported:

```
static FILE *debugOut = stderr;
static FILE *infoOut = stdout;
```

The error that the gcc return is:

```
initializer element is not constant
```

Comment: you need to post more code as this is not enough, also is it all that gcc is reporting? also try assigning them in a function (i think you are doing it now as global variables?)

Comment: You're initializing a static variable, which means the compiler needs to know what the value is at compile time. You're trying to assign a value that isn't knowable to the compiler at compile time but knows at run time - this is why it's causing the error.

Comment: It's not a duplicate - its more specific than the linked question - a good answer would go into detail why stderr/stdout are constant expressions in some c libraries - but not in all - and that the C standard does not require it that they are constant expressions. And then add some portable variants of the above code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ANSI C standard does not demand that `stderr`/`stdout` have to be constant expressions.

Thus, depending on the used standard C library code like this

```
static FILE *debugOut = stderr;
```

compiles or yields the error message you have asked about.

For example, the [GNU C library defines](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/FAQ#I_get_compiler_messages_.22Initializer_element_not_constant.22_with_stdin.2BAC8-stdout.2BAC8-stderr.__Why.3F) `stderr`/`stdout`/`stdin` as non-constant expressions.

You have basically two options to deal with this situation, i.e. to make such code portable.

### Initialization from main

```
static FILE *debugOut = NULL;
static FILE *infoOut  = NULL;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  debugOut = stderr;
  infoOut  = stdout;
  // [..] 
  return 0;
}
```

### Initialization from a constructor function

On many platforms you can declare a function as constructor, meaning that it is called on startup before `main()` is called. For example when using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) you can implement it like this:

```
static FILE *debugOut = NULL;
static FILE *infoOut  = NULL;

static void init_streams(void) __attribute__((constructor)); 
static void init_streams(void)
{
  debugOut = stderr;
  infoOut  = stdout;
}
```

This [constructor attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bconstructor_007d-function-attribute-2844) syntax is not standardized, but since GCC is very widespread and other compilers strive for GCC compatibility this is actually quite portable.

In case you need to make this portable to other compilers that does not have a similar declaration feature you can guard this code with macros like `__GNU_LIBRARY__` and/or `__GNUC__`.

Answer (score 8):

try doing it in main for example:

```
static FILE *debugOut;
static FILE *infoOut;

main(){
    debugOut = stderr;
    infoOut = stdout;


}
```

Answer (score 3):

From the C99 standard:

> **6.7.8 Initialization**
>
> **Constraints**
>
> 4 All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static storage duration shall be constant expressions or string literals.

Hence,

```
static FILE *debugOut = stderr;
static FILE *infoOut = stdout;
```

is not legal code if compiler does not think `stderr` and `stdout` are constant expressions.

This is what the standard has to say about `stderr` and `stdout`.

> **7.19 Input/output `<stdio.h>`**
>
> **7.19.1 Introduction**
>
> ...
>
> ```
>    stderr
>    stdin
>    stdout
> ```
>
> which are expressions of type ‘‘pointer to `FILE`’’ that point to the `FILE` objects associated, respectively, with the standard error, input, and output streams.

**Solution**

The standard compliant way to deal with this is to initialize the variables to `NULL` and set their values in `main`.

```
static FILE *debugOut = NULL;
static FILE *infoOut  = NULL;

int main()
{
  debugOut = stderr;
  infoOut  = stdout;

  ...
```

Comment: @AndreasL. my initial answer was to point out the problem. I added a solution.

Comment: Thank you. I am migrating old code and I have no main method, so I do a check ( if ( file == NULL ) {
   file = stdout;
  } ) in every method "file" is used. "file" could have been set at other place...