# "error: initializer element is not constant" in 16 year old code

Tags: c, linux, gcc, compilation

I am trying to compile a Linux C program that is 16 years old. Anyway. i've come quite far with just editing the Makefile and changing compilers to an older version. I am now faced with what i think is a bug that will only compile in an older compiler, although i cannot choose an older one as that would ruin the system solution. I am not well versed in C. 
Im using Gentoo linux and GCC version 3.4.6 when trying to compile this.

```
./src/radcheck.c:97: error: initializer element is not constant
make: *** [src/radcheck.o] Error 1
```

The code in question, File *msgfd = stderr; is the offending line 97.

```
FILE           *ddt = NULL;
FILE           *msgfd = stderr;
extern void     dir_init ();
```

What i can tell from reading about this error online this code needs to be rewritten?

If anyone can help me troubleshoot this issue i would be really happy!

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623735/error-initializer-element-is-not-constant

Comment: I figured id out due to this link. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FILE *msgfd = stderr;
```

An object at global scope cannot be initialized by a non-constant. This is the case in all Standard C versions. In your previous implementation: either the compiler was permissive to allow it as an extension or `stderr` was an address constant. To fix the error, put the initialization (using an assignment) in an init function.

Comment: note: by "an init function", obviously this has to be done before calling any function that relies on `msgfd`, so a good place would either be the start of `main` , or a function you add in that is called from the start of `main` and it initializes static data.

Comment: This is all greek to me. Can you help me with some code examples and i will probably be able to adapt it into this code. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Plindgren `FILE *msgfd; int main(void) { msgfd = stderr; /* ... */ }`

Comment: There has to be a better answer than this. I've got a program with thousands of this error that used to compile with no problem at all. It's just not feasible to edit the source and make it conform to the obtuse requirements of C compilers these days.